# What does "assignment" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the following passage, what does **assignment** mean in the context of *sex assignment surgery*? Does it mean *assign:* [*to give a particular value, identity, etc., to something*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/assign)?

> Germany, the first European country to make such an allowance, reviewed cases of intersex babies and found that many who were subjected to sex **assignment** surgery at a young age ended up unhappy.
>
> -- *[www.newser.com: Germany Creates 3rd Gender](http://www.newser.com/story/176872/germany-creates-3rd-gender.html)*

Comment: General Reference - [Sex reassignment surgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_reassignment_surgery), plus a dictionary definition of [assign](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assign)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not quite sure which definitions is appropriate from the link you gave, the definitions on the regular dictionary doesn't seem to relate to surgeries/medical procedures. Could it be the first definition of *assignment* from the medical dictionary: *the selection of something for a specific purpose?* But then the example it provides doesn't seem to fit the context.

Comment: I'm not going to wade through various definitions appropriate to other contexts and select the one most relevant to *this* context. You can do that for yourself once you've digested the implications of the fact that *gender **reassignment** surgery* applies to people whose *current* gender is (relatively) clearly established.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think it's that obvious to go from “sex assignment surgery” to “sex REassignment surgery” (and then go back and correctly infer what taking out the re- prefix entails) and to figure out that this is the right compound to analyze as a unit.

Comment: @Gilles: Obviously there's no *definitive* distinction between "assignment" and "reassignment" in OP's exact context. Suppose an ultrasound scan had revealed the clear presence of penises on twin foetuses, for example, and the parents-to-be had therefore already assigned male names to both before birth. Further suppose that subsequent DNA tests show one to be 99% female at the chromosomal level, and the other 99% male, but they both have ambiguous genitalia. I think it's pointless debating whether the surgery for one should be *assignment*, where for the other it's ***reassignment***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *sex assignment surgery* suggests that the sex of the baby is ambiguous.

Usually, the doctors will let the parents choose which sex for the baby. This surgery will then make the baby's gender unambiguous, thus the term **assignment**.

Obviously, according to your article, the older approach must be problematic.

Comment: Just to clarify, so does *assign* then means *to make unambiguous (as to gender)*?

Comment: Only in this specific context, yes. By the way, according to the dictionary link you have given, the sense you suggested is the closest one.